# UIButton has strange unexpected bakground color on different device

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton, uikit

I've recently been building an app under iOS 15 (latest as of writing this code), and when I shipped a version of my app to test flight, one of my users sent me a video of the app working, and I noticed, all of my buttons have this strange background highlight effect. Is this some sort of accessibility mode? I've never seen this happen before. In included some screenshots below and the interface builder, there are no custom classes associated to this UIButton. And ALL of the buttons have this effect happening to them.

**This other device has a strange background color attached:**
[image: This other device has a strange background color attached.]

**But this is how its designed and how it shows up on my device and the simulator:**
[image: But this is how its designed and how it shows up on my device and the simulator]

Here is a screenshot from Interface Builder:
[image: Here is a screenshot from Interface Builder]

Comment: Hrm. I thought maybe the type being System was the problem, but I switched it to that, and still this strange behavior...

Answer (score 1):

This happens on specific iOS devices. Following are the simple steps to resolve this issue:

1. Open **Settings** and search for **Accessibility**.
2. In **Accessibility**, there is **Display & Text Size**, tap it.
3. There is a toggle button for **Button Shapes**, **close** the toggle button.

Following these steps will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

Change the style to `default`.
And then instead of the `tint color`, choose the `text color`.
The background can remain `default`.. and is therefore transparency.

Tested, works.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOicq.png)

Comment: Thank you for trying, I also followed your direction exactly and pushed a new version, but on that one device, they still have this strange background color on their UIButtons :(

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my user had something in iOS accessibility settings turned on, called "Button Shapes". I had no idea...